# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types when password or username not found

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stored-procedures, forms-authentication

I am creating a dual login form that authenticates the user based on their role and redirects them to a specific page based on their username and password. I was originally using `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` to handle the redirection but I found that I can only redirect to one page upon successful login using the

```
<forms defaultUrl="~/InteriorStudentPortal.aspx" loginUrl="~/ExteriorLogin.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
```

authentication in my web.config. Instead I am using a simple `Response.Redirect("~/InteriorStudentPortal.aspx")` property in the back code of the login page. Now when a user enters an incorrect username or password I am getting an `Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types` error that was normally handled by the `FormsAuthentication`. What can I add to my back code or stored procedure to handle this exception?

Here is one of my stored procs:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Validate_Student]

      @Username NVARCHAR(50),

      @Password NVARCHAR(50)

AS

BEGIN

      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      DECLARE @StudentID INT, @LastLoginDate DATETIME



      SELECT @StudentID = StudentID, @LastLoginDate = LastLoginDate 

      FROM Student WHERE [Username] = @Username AND [Password] = @Password



      IF @Username IS NOT NULL

      BEGIN

        UPDATE Student

        SET LastLoginDate = GETDATE()

        WHERE StudentID = @StudentID

        SELECT @StudentID [StudentID] -- User Valid

      END

      BEGIN

            SELECT -1 -- User invalid.

      END

END
```

Along with the back code:

```
Protected Sub ValidateStudent(sender As Object, e As AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles Login1.Authenticate
        Dim studentId As Integer = 0
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DatabaseConnectionString").ConnectionString

            Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Validate_Student")
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Login1.Password)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    con.Open()
                studentId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            Select Case studentId
                Case -1
                    Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect."
                    Exit Select
                Case Else
                    Response.Redirect("~/InteriorStudentPortal.aspx")
                    Exit Select
            End Select
            End Using
    End Sub
```

The error occurs on the `studentId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())` line. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I would be happy to provide any additional information needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for DBNull like below

```
studentId = If(IsDBNull(cmd.ExecuteScalar()), 0, Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()))
```

and modify

```
Select Case studentId
       Case -1
         Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect."
       Exit Select
       Case 0
         Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect."
       Exit Select
       Case Else
         Response.Redirect("~/InteriorStudentPortal.aspx")
       Exit Select
End Select
```

or you can use `IF ELSE` instead of `CASE`

```
If studentId > 0 Then
    Response.Redirect("~/InteriorStudentPortal.aspx")
Else
    Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect."
End If
```

Comment: @NOSDUH Yeah, not really, that's an awful answer: [VB.NET - Blind leading the blind - IIf](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bJxrFe)

Comment: @NOSDUH answer revamped, In case you caught any exception

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå  here is the answer for you gentleman https://dotnetfiddle.net/ESETAH

Comment: @Vivek.S That's indeed the correct tool to use. And you naming me a gentleman (I'm a programmer BTW) doesn't make your initial answer any better. I'm not the one posting a poor answer, you did, so don't blame me.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I don't wanna start O/T comments here and I ain't a boastful person,so have a nice day *again* gentleman